# Microsoft Access SQL Apply

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to use the below query in an access environment to no avail. The problem seems to be with the APPLY. However, this runs fine directly on our SQL server..... Help?

```
SELECT 
    dbo_tblmain.key1, 
    dbo_tblmain.key2, 
    dbo_tblmain.data1, 
    dbo_tblmain.data2, 
    dbo_tblmain.data3, 
    dbo_tblsupp.data1,
    tbloutmade.data1
FROM dbo_tblmain 
LEFT JOIN dbo_tblsupp 
ON (dbo_tblmain.key1 = dbo_tblsupp.key1) AND (dbo_tblmain.key2 = dbo_tblsupp.key2)
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo_tbloutside WHERE LEFT(dbo_tblmain.key1,14)=LEFT(dbo_tbloutside.key1,14)) tbloutmade;
```

sample data

```
tblmain
key1          key2                data1 data2 data3 
A1234567890   12345678901234AAA   AAA   BBB   CCC   

tblsupp
key1          key2                data1
A1234567890   12345678901234AAA   DDD

tbloutside
key1                 data1
12345678901234AAABB  EEE
```

Comment: Are you running against an SQL Server, would a passthrough query suit?

Comment: @remou Not sure. I haven't used a passthrough query before. I'm running against linked tables that are connected to an SQL Server, but I'm using the SQL view of the report builder in Access. I'm more of a straight SQL guy, not an access guru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_tblmain.key1, 
    dbo_tblmain.key2, 
    dbo_tblmain.data1, 
    dbo_tblmain.data2, 
    dbo_tblmain.data3, 
    dbo_tblsupp.data1,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Key1 FROM dbo_tbloutside 
     WHERE LEFT(dbo_tblmain.key1,14)=LEFT(dbo_tbloutside.key1,14)) As tbloutmade
FROM dbo_tblmain 
LEFT JOIN dbo_tblsupp 
ON (dbo_tblmain.key1 = dbo_tblsupp.key1) 
AND (dbo_tblmain.key2 = dbo_tblsupp.key2)
```

Comment: You cannot select a table in the select portion. Only singular data can be selected. While TOP 1 is singular, it still comes across as a result set not a single column. However, I can put a single column (data1) in place of * and your method works.

Comment: There is a problem with Top in MS Access and that is that it will return matched results, so whether you need the sql amended depends on your data. If you either post sample data or reply with additional information, I can give a firmer answer. Otherwise, the above should run, it is valid Access (Jet/ACE) sql.

Comment: Added some sample data. The above does not run, but if i get rid of the tbloutmade.data1 and change the * to a single column like data1 it runs. What's the issue with Top in MS Access?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is late :) The problem with Top is that it returns matches and you must have a single result returned for the query to work, so you may have to order by a unique index. If a query does not suit MS Access, it is possible to run passthrough queries, these are written in MS Access but run in SQL Server against an ODBC connection.

Comment: [How to create an SQL pass-through query in Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968)

Comment: Pass-through interests me. The straight forward method works fine for this query, but i may just start using pass-through on several others. thanks!